# merge_oracle_ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, merge

I am trying to do a merge in oracle:

```
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement("MERGE INTO dev_corpus a " +
                          "USING (SELECT ? corpusid, ? corpus_name, ? corpusdesc, ? corpusimageids, ? rocf1, ? rocf2, ? rocf3, ? rocc1, ? rocc2, ? rocc3, ? corpusactive, ? corpusrunfrequency, ? corpuslastrun, ? corpuslastsync, ? rocsettingid, ? corpusaffinity, ? corpusterms, ? corpusdomain FROM dual) incoming " +
                          "ON (a.corpusid = incoming.corpusid ) " +
                          "WHEN MATCHED THEN " +
                          "UPDATE SET (a.corpus_name = incoming.corpus_name AND a.corpusdesc = incoming.corpusdesc AND a.corpusimageids = incoming.corpusimageids AND a.rocf1 = incoming.rocf1 AND a.rocf2 = incoming.rocf2 AND a.rocf3 = incoming.rocf3 AND a.rocc1 = incoming.rocc1 AND a.rocc2 = incoming.rocc2 AND a.rocc3 = incoming.rocc3 AND a.corpusactive = incoming.corpusactive AND a.corpusrunfrequency = incoming.corpusrunfrequency AND a.corpuslastrun = incoming.corpuslastrun AND a.corpuslastsync = incoming.corpuslastsync AND a.rocsettingid = incoming.rocsettingid AND a.corpusaffinity = incoming.corpusaffinity AND a.corpusterms = incoming.corpusterms AND a.corpusdomain = incoming.corpusdomain) " +
                          "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN " +
                          "INSERT (a.corpusid, a.corpus_name, a.corpusdesc, a.corpusimageids, a.rocf1, a.rocf2, a.rocf3, a.rocc1, a.rocc2, a.rocc3, a.corpusactive, a.corpusrunfrequency, a.corpuslastrun, a.corpuslastsync, a.rocsettingid, a.corpusaffinity, a.corpusterms, a.corpusdomain) " +
                          "VALUES (incoming.corpusid, incoming.corpus_name, incoming.corpusdesc, incoming.corpusimageids, incoming.rocf1, incoming.rocf2, incoming.rocf3, incoming.rocc1, incoming.rocc2, incoming.rocc3, incoming.corpusactive, incoming.corpusrunfrequency, incoming.corpuslastrun, incoming.corpuslastsync, incoming.rocsettingid, incoming.corpusaffinity, incoming.corpusterms, incoming.corpusdomain)");
```

and I get this error:

```
    ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:505)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:223)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1044)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1328)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3593)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3674)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1354)
    at com.mycompany.datalayer.DB.insertToTaxonomy(DB.java:261)
    at com.mycompany.datalayer.DB.restoreBackUp(DB.java:94)
    at com.mycompany.datalayer.DB.startProcess(DB.java:56)
    at com.mycompany.oraclebackup.App.main(App.java:13)
```

now, I have checked the column names they are correct. 
do you know what is the problem? and how can I solve it?
(p.s:I am not using hibernate)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Java Prepared statement you can use '?' only for column names in where clause. You are trying to extend this concept to other places, which is invalid. Here is the problematic section in your code:

```
SELECT ? corpusid, ? corpus_name, ? corpusdesc
```

Here is the Note from [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html):

> **Note**: The setter methods (setShort, setString, and so on) for setting IN parameter values must specify types that are compatible
>   with the defined SQL type of the input parameter. For instance, if the
>   IN parameter has SQL type INTEGER, then the method setInt should be
>   used.

Comment: Thanks for the note! I need to update a row in the table if it exists otherwise insert it to table. considering that the data is passed to the class(is not from a table, so somehow I need to use preparedstatment or something like that).Now, If I cant use '?' in here, is there any alternative? or any wayaround for this? Thank you!!

Comment: @user149855 You may have to do the string manipulation of your sql query string.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the fields like corpusid,corpusimageids etc may not be stored as String-related datatypes(for eg. varchar) in dev_corpus table in the database. They might be integer or number fields.

I feel they are being passed as string fields when you replace the parameters in '?' (for e.g. You might be using a string array to pass these parameters). In which case you must ensure you handle the parameter's datatype in your query itself, with reference to the datatypes used in the table dev_corpus.

For eg. assuming that the field corpusid is of type number in your database table, your query should be :

```
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement("MERGE INTO dev_corpus a " +
                          "USING (SELECT to_number(?) corpusid, ? corpus_name, ? corpusdesc, ? corpusimageids, ? rocf1,..."
```

Any fields other than String fields(char,varchar) may require such special attention.e.g

```
to_date(column_name,'dd-mm-yyyy')
```